# What does the following argument in a terminal command mean: ./

Tags: go, command-line

I'm trying to execute some code from the following book:
Learning Go - An Idiomatic Approach to Real-World Go Programming *written by* Jon Bodner

The first chapter talks about making a Makefile to automate executing certain commands, like the `go fmt some_code.go` command.
The book says that writing the command like this: `go fmt ./...` will cause the command to run over your entire project.

However when I try to run this command I get the following error:

> pattern ./...: directory prefix . does not contain main module or its
> selected dependencies

When I try to look up this ./... argument online, I can't find anything.

So I was wondering what this argument does in the command line.

By the way I'm using a zsh terminal on a MacOS system.

So if anybody knows what this ./... means, what I am doing wrong or what I am supposed to be doing, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.hacksparrow.com/nodejs/directory-references.html is written for node.js, but the principle applies here as well. `The usage of ./ and ../ come from operating system relative directory dot notations. ./ refers to the present working directory (a.k.a current working directory), ../ refers to the parent of the present working directory.`

Comment: FWIW, I ran into this issue because I did not have a go.mod file. I ran: `go mod init <package-name>` and no longer ran into the issue mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The package specification `./...` refers to packages in the current file system directory and all subdirectories.

The error from your `go fmt` command invocation indicates that the `go` tool could not find any packages in the directory.  Perhaps you need to create a go.mod file.

The `go` command documentation describes the `./...` feature. Here are the relevant quotes:

The section on [relative import paths](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Relative_import_paths) says:

> An import path beginning with ./ or ../ is called a relative path. The toolchain supports relative import paths as a shortcut in two ways.

> First, a relative path can be used as a shorthand on the command line. If you are working in the directory containing the code imported as "unicode" and want to run the tests for "unicode/utf8", you can type "go test ./utf8" instead of needing to specify the full path. Similarly, in the reverse situation, "go test .." will test "unicode" from the "unicode/utf8" directory. Relative patterns are also allowed, like "go test ./..." to test all subdirectories. See 'go help packages' for details on the pattern syntax.

The section on [package patterns](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns) says:

> An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "..." wildcards, each of which can match any string, including the empty string and strings containing slashes. Such a pattern expands to all package directories found in the GOPATH trees with names matching the patterns.